Airflow - Dynamic mapped Task Group - Removing mapped task dependencies for all the sub task, and access mapped_input in task group directly
I am working with Airflow and have created a DAG that uses dynamic task mapping inside a task group.
I have two questions:

How to remove the line from get_files to process_file_step2?

I want process_file_step1 to be the only upstream task of process_file_step2, even though the input (file_path) is received from get_files.
How can I modify the DAG to remove this dependency? As shown in the attached DAG graph, there is an unwanted direct line from get_files to process_file_step2.


How to get the file name inside the task group by parsing the dynamically mapped input?

Inside the task group, I need to parse input directly and use it for downstream tasks
I have added a TODO placeholder for this in the example dag code below but am unsure how to correctly implement it.



Example DAG and graph are attached below
from airflow.decorators import dag, task_group, task
from airflow.operators.empty import EmptyOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

@dag(
    start_date=days_ago(1),
    schedule=None,
    catchup=False
)
def dynamic_task_group_mapping():
    @task_group(group_id="process_file")
    def tg1(file_path):
        @task
        def process_file_step1(file_path):
            return f"Step 1 processed {file_path}"

        @task
        def process_file_step2(file_path):
            return f"Step 2 processed {file_path}"

        process_file_step1(file_path) >> process_file_step2(file_path)

        # # TODO: how to parse file_path to get file name
        # from pathlib import Path
        # file_name = Path(file_path).name
        # return file_name

    @task
    def get_files():
        return ['file1', 'file2', 'file3']

    tg1.expand(file_path=get_files()) >> EmptyOperator(task_id='Notify', trigger_rule="none_failed_min_one_success")

dynamic_task_group_mapping()

DAG Graph:  I want to avoid line/dependency from get_files to process_file_step2


Your process_file_step2 depends on file_path - which is an input to the task group, so that's why you have the dependency.
If you want to have only step1 -> step2 dependency you have to return the file path by step1 (and make step2 depend on step1) - with passing output of step1 as input to step2 rather than addding dependency using `>>`` - see  https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/tutorial/taskflow.html#example-taskflow-api-pipeline
Smth like that:
def process_file_step1(path):
    # do stuff
    return path

step1_output = process_file_step1(file_path)
step2_output = process_file_step2(step1_output)

See

Yes, I understand that, but is there a way to not have it if I choose not to.
Or May be have a dependency to task group as a whole without dependency on any of the tasks inside it?

We may not necessarily have all the sub tasks to have their output based on the inputs to the next task.
One alternative I see is to send the file_path to xcom_push in the step1 and then use xcom_pull in step2, but I don't want to assume their is no alternative today.
